# Update panda dataframe to SQL Server though SQLAlchemy engine using python

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have an existing SQL Server Database. I want to use python to read from a CSV file and update column values matching the TIMEID column into the SQL Server Table

If I do it in SQL Server I would load the the new CSV into a new table and then update using:

```
UPDATE R 
SET R.[PA]=P.[PA]
FROM [DATABASE_TABLE] AS R
INNER JOIN [NEW_CSV] AS P 
       ON R.[TIMEID] = P.[TIMEID] 
WHERE R.[TIMEID] like '20180201%' //i can survive now without the where, and update everything from the CSV.
```

Pretty new to python so pardon me. I have succeeded loading the CSV file into a panda dataframe and also I am able to insert new rows into the SQL Server but I am unable to manage an update (either into existing columns or null columns).

```
import pandas as pd 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("BLOCKOUTFOR PASSWORD")
query="SELECT * FROM [DATABASE].[TABLE]"
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
display(df) #This is just to display the current data

    TIMEID  DATEID  HOUR    DOW FESTIVAL    PA  PB  PC  P31A    PX  PY  P_TOT
0   20180101H01 2018-01-01  01  2   N   0.4615  0.0570  0.4427  0.0153  None    None    0.9765
1   20180101H02 2018-01-01  02  2   N   0.4112  0.0516  0.4074  0.0154  None    None    0.8856

#Convert Type and Load CSV into df3
def dfReadCSV( Path, Ind):
    df =pd.read_csv(Path,dtype={'DATEID':str,'Hour':str},parse_dates= ['DATEID'])
    df1=df[Ind:]
    return df1
df3=dfReadCSV("C5Liq_2018Test.csv",0)

display(df3) #if there is a neater way to do this it be appreciated, but not critical 

    Attribute   TIMEID  DATEID  Hour    DOW 20A 20DHA   21A 21DHA   30A 31A PA  PB  PC  P31A    P_TOT
0   H01 20180101H01 2018-01-01  01  1   0.2953  0.0158  0.1662  0.0412  0.4427  0.0153  0.4615  0.0570  0.4427  0.0153  0.9765
1   H02 20180101H02 2018-01-01  02  1   0.2711  0.0160  0.1401  0.0356  0.4074  0.0154  0.4112  0.0516  0.4074  0.0154  0.8856

#Insert Function
connStr= engine.connect().connection
cursor = connStr.cursor()

for index,row in df3.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO [DATABASE].[TABLE]([TIMEID],[DATEID],[Hour],[DOW]) values (?,?,?,?)', row['TIMEID'], row['DATEID'], row['Hour'], row['DOW']) 
    connStr.commit()

cursor.close()
connStr.close()

#Update Function. This is where i have problem.
connStr= engine.connect().connection
cursor = connStr.cursor()

for row in df3.iterrows():
    #sql = 'UPDATE [DATABASE].[TABLE] SET [DATEID]=? WHERE [TIMEID]=?'.format(tbl=[DATABASE].[TABLE])
   cursor.execute("UPDATE [DATABASE].[TABLE]  SET [DATEID] = ? WHERE [TIMEID] = ?", row[:,0],row[;,0])  

cursor.close()
connStr.close()
```

The Syntax is wrong and I couldn't figure it out. Preferable I like to have a similar method to update as above.Data in the CSV get updated and I want to update these info into my SQL Server table.

I have found a similiar thread but found no answer too:
[Update MSSQL table through SQLAlchemy using dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563790/update-mssql-table-through-sqlalchemy-using-dataframes)

As the threadstarter there, I too cannot drop the table because the new CSV that I load in a new column of data(example PX) might not have some info of the previous insert (PA).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make an update you want:

1) Directly on the database:

```
upd = (session.query(TABLE)
       .filter(TIMEID = row[:,0])
       .update({"DATEID": row[:,0]})
       )
print("# of updated rows = {}".format(upd))
# session.commit()
```

2) Load object(s), update the value, and commit the session

```
upd = (session.query(TABLE)
       .filter(TIMEID = row[:,0])
       )

# assuming there should be exactly one object for given TIMEID
DATEID= upd.one()
DATEID.time_out = datetime.datetime.now()
session.commit()
```

You can get more [info](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html)

I don't recommend sqlachemy for updation. its good for batch insert

For sqlalchemy

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@host:port/database')
print(engine)
truncate_query = "SELECT * from something.something"
df = pd.read_sql_query(truncate_query , engine)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.
i started with the SQLACHEMY just because of the import create_engine,hoping to find a solution similiar to using Cursor.excute function.


I tried your solution and franky have little knowledge of using session etc.
Apart from the code you advised, I add the below in to the definition, after checking out the link

//from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session=sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session() //

1st solution 1) Directly on the database:

//NameError: name 'TABLE' is not defined//
I am finding difficulty to define the session.querry()?

Comment: I know it might have been a novice qns, but I am just confused by the diffierent ways to archieve one same thing.I like to understand how to make the querry.session work but at the same time I was thinking if there exist(maybe it not possible?) :  to have the update similiar to insert in the line of:
//
    connStr= engine.connect().connection
    cursor = connStr.cursor()

    for index,row in df3.iterrows():
    cursor.execute(SOME UPDATE STATEMENT)
    connStr.commit()

    cursor.close() 
    connStr.close()
//
Thanks everyone for any info , regards

Comment: NameError: name 'TABLE' is not defined// Here you have to replace with your table name

Comment: index is used for indexing of row data I don't say why loop is failing without index as it should not.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my solution, after hours of searching:

Update function

```
connStr= engine.connect().connection
cursor = connStr.cursor()

for index, row in df3.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('''UPDATE [DATABASE].[TABLE] SET [Hour] = ? WHERE [TIMEID] = ?''', (row['Hour'],row['TIMEID']))  
    connStr.commit()
    

cursor.close()
connStr.close()
```

After hours of trying, its an straight forward syntax error.

I still like to hear about how i can have the solution using the session.query method.

And I am sure if there my above code could be better if some error checking.
At the same time if some one can explain why the loop fails without the 'Index' and what it means?

```
for index, row in df3.iterrows():
```

Tired but excited.